# Get array results of OData JSON query in Javascript with dynamic field parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, odata

The second part of my odata routine is below as getFieldData and func1 as a simplified first part. alert1 works and alert2 does not. How can I make alert2 work? I want the routine to be reusable by other functions but need to pass the parameter to do that. I'm just not sure how to get the parameter to work properly.

```
function func1(){
    var param1 = 'FullName';
    getFieldData(this,param1);
}

function getFieldData(retrieveReq,param1) {
    if (retrieveReq.readyState == 4 && retrieveReq.status == 200) {
       var retrieved = this.parent.JSON.parse(retrieveReq.responseText).d;
       alert('alert1: ' + retrieved.results[0].FullName);
       alert('alert2: ' + retrieved.results[0].param1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change it like:

```
alert('alert2: ' + retrieved.results[0][param1]);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Will mark as answer as soon as the system lets me. (said I had to wait 7 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Use [bracket notation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
alert('alert2: ' + retrieved.results[0][param1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For consuming an odata service on javascript client, you could consider using the source code packages, e.g. JayData, Breeze and datajs.